# I can run Robotium test but cannot debug it

Tags: android, robotium

I'm testing an apk for which I don't have sources on my phone.  I have ensured that I have the same certificates in both the test and app apks.  I'm able to run my tests fine from eclipse, but when I try to debug through "Debug As", eclipse appears to be stuck launching the tests.  In the progress bar at the bottom, I see "Launching: Creating source locator...".  I have set breakpoints in the appropriate spots, and nothing that I can see in the logcat output to suggest that there's a crash in either the test process or the app process.  Any ideas on what the problem might be or how to investigate further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems.

The solution for me was that there may only be one DDMS instance running. So for example if I had the tools/ddms.bat running while at the same time eclipse was opened, then the debugging didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I posted as well for the same question, and I figured it out. [cannot run as debug robotium junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203360/cannot-run-as-debug-robotium-junit-test/13203528#13203528)

So there is two requirements to get this to work:

1. you need to have the AUT (App Under Test) setup in your workspace 2. the AUT must be debuggable=true (manifest file)
2. my mistake was that because I wanted to debug the test only I did not think that I needed the AUT project also.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was that I needed to check my device display. I realised that there was a dialog with a question, but since this dialog blocked the device, the test could not run...