# cannot run as debug robotium junit test

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit, robotium

I guess this is a duplicate with [I can run Robotium test but cannot debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573833/i-can-run-robotium-test-but-cannot-debug-it) but there is no valid answer for it.

I have a application that I can test with robotium. (Run as Android Junit Test the test runs fine)
If I try Debug As Android Junit Test, the application does not start, eclipse appears to be stuck launching the tests.

Can you tell me the steps in order to run my test in debug mode (I want to debug the test, not the app)?

Answer (score 0):

So there is two requirement to get this to work:
1. you need to have the AUT (App Under Test) setup in your workspace
2. the AUT must be debuggable=true (manifest file)

my mistake was that because I wanted to debug the test only I did not think that I needed the AUT project also.