# Can't launch Android JUnit Test in Eclipse. Stuck at: Launching: Creating source locator

Tags: android, junit

I am a novice at Android JUnit Test:

I wrote a class(I named it XmlTest.java) that extending AndroidTestCase in order to test my Android project in Eclipse.

When I right clicked XmlTest.java and then chose "Run As->Android JUnit Test", Eclipse appeared to be stuck launching the test. In the progress bar at the bottom, I saw "Launching: Creating source locator...".

<[I can run Robotium test but cannot debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573833/i-can-run-robotium-test-but-cannot-debug-it)>
This guy had the similar problem. But the solution didn't work for me. I have also tried rebooting my PC, but the problem persists.

Is there anyone who know how to fix this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded another Eclipse and everything worked fine in the new Eclipse.

So maybe there was something corrupted in my previous Eclipse. Weired!